# Flutter full platform adaptiveness for iOS and Android

Tags: flutter, adaptive-layout

I would like to introduce full platform adaptiveness to my app. Currently I use `Material` for both iOS and Android version. I would like to show appropriate version of Widget depending on detected platform but I don't want to do this as shown on following code sample, because I have to do it multiple times for existing app.

**Solution #1**

```
 return Theme.of(context).targetPlatform = TargetPlatform.iOS
        ? CupertinoTextField(
            ...)
        : TextField(
            ...)
```

**Solution #2**
Fortunately, there are widgets like with `adaptive` named constructor like `Switch.adaptive` and works perfectly for me. Unfortunately you can count them on the fingers of one hand.

**Solution #3**
Use 3rd party library and. For example I can use `PlatformButton` where possible and don't care what happens under the hood.

> [flutter_platform_widgets 1.10.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets)

**Solution #4**
Write custom [platform specific wrapper](https://medium.com/flutter/do-flutter-apps-dream-of-platform-aware-widgets-7d7ed7b4624d) for each widget according to this tutorial.

---

**Question #1**
Which solution is the best considering time and testability? I'm big fan of Flutter's widget with `.adaptive` named constructor but I can't wait until Flutter Dev team provide more similar widgets

**Question #2**
How to handle tests for iOS specific widgets using Firebase Test Lab? Should I write unit test to check if proper iOS version of widget is rendered? I see there is no other way.